# How do I correctly multicolumn tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, width

How do I correctly multicolumn a tabularx while preserving the correct width?

When relatively short content is inserted into the `\multicolumn`, it can be done with `l`, `c`, or `r`. However, if the content does not fit into the width of the multi-column, one needs either `X` or `p` and the correct width must be computed. This question asks how to do this.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\sbl}{\tiny Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.}

\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{X|X|X|X|X}
  \hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & c\hfill 5\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & \sbl\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & \multicolumn{4}{X}{\sbl}\\\hline
  \multicolumn{5}{X}{\sbl}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendering of mwe]

Using `2\hsize` does not do the trick as suggested many a place.

```
c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 &
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}X}{\sbl}\\\hline % <--- does not work
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with from various information I found was to introduce a new macro (`\Xwdth`) to pre-compute the size, taking into account additional width variables. Then I created a multicolumn wrapper `\multiX` for convenience.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\Xwdth}[1]{\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep+#1\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\newcommand{\multiX}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\hsize=\Xwdth{#1}}X}{#2}}
\newcommand{\multiXr}[2][1]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\hsize=\Xwdth{#1}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}{#2}}

\newcommand{\sbl}{\tiny Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.}

\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{X|X|X|X|X}
  \hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & c\hfill 5\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & \sbl\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & c\hfill 4 & \multiX{1}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & c\hfill 3 & \multiX{2}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & c\hfill 2 & \multiX{3}{\sbl}\\\hline
  c\hfill 1 & \multiX{4}{\sbl}\\\hline
  \multiX{5}{\sbl}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: solution rendering]

Comment: that is the answer (it is harder, basically not supported if you need to span ove l columns of unknown width) (it is better to make the table full width and then suppress the paragraph indent with `\noindent` before the table)