# Creating tables with multiple rows and columns with lists and very long text

Tags: tables, lists, line-breaking, multicolumn, multirow

I am trying to create the following table with LaTeX:

[image]

I have tried using *makecell*, *tabularx*, and *array* packages. However, I can't create it. I can't make the table have a maximum width equal to **\linewidth**, while breaking long text correctly into multiple lines and creating bulleted lists in the table cells. What I have tried so far is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Example Table}
    \label{example-table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2}\linewidth|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Example Table} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{very long text} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{very long text} \\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{long text} & %
            \multirow{2}{*}{long text} & %
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{very very \\ long text}} & %
            \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{very very \\ long text}} \\
            \cline{4-5}
             & & & \makecell{very very \\ long text} & \makecell{very very \\ long text} \\
             \hline
            \makecell{\begin{itemize \item very very long text \item second very very long text \end{itemize}} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone have ideas or know how to implement the table with LaTeX? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why did you choose to write `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.2}\linewidth|X|}` rather than, say, `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{X|}}`? Should final column really be a lot narrower than the first four? Please advise.

Comment: Hey @Mico, thanks. I tried p{0.2\linewidth}, because I thought I could restrain the table size and therefore keep the text from going over the vertical table lines and having automatic linebreaks in the cells. Other than that no particular reason. I am also new to latex, so there might be some stupid stuff happening in the code ...

Comment: I'm reluctant -- actually, *unwilling* -- too post an answer that fully implements the layout shown in your screenshot, as I think that parts of the layout you show are highly problematic. In particular, the partial overlaps of rows in column 1, columns 2-4, and columns 5-6 are bound to cause no end of uncertainty and confusion among your readers. Do you absolutely, positively have to come up with a exact LaTeX-based implementation of the layout shown in your screenshot?

Comment: @Mico there is a table like this in a scientific book, which I want to cite and use in my work. I know it looks really problematic, but I am not sure what to do. I could split the table up or try to change the cell positions... do you suggest I exactly quote the source with the table, or rather change it and try to make it more clear and latex friendly?

Comment: I would definitely recommend the latter approach -- simplify and streamline the table's design. A personal remark: I cannot imagine *any* readers giving you kudos for managing to replicate somebody else's convoluted and ambiguous table layout.

Comment: Alright,  I think I'll go do that. Thank you for your help @Mico.

Comment: Your code is really different from the picture. For example, your code has 5 columns, but the picture has 6. And the first row in your code consists of a 2-column cell followed by a 3-column cell, but the picture has 4 single column cells and a 2-column cell.

Comment: Yes @PietervanOostrum I know. As I'm a LaTeX noob, I couldn't get any closer to what I wanted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. The last four cells I have left blank because they are basically the same as the previous one.

**NOTE 1:** You probably will have to adjust the `\multirow` 'nrows' parameter to reflect the actual number of **lines** covered rather than the number of **rows**.

**NOTE 2:** It is probably better to put the table in a landscape page because it is quite wide.

**NOTE 3:** I used `paralist` to get more compact item lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\newcommand{\itemlist}[1]{%
  \setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{}{}{}{}{}
  \begin{compactitem}#1\end{compactitem}%
}

% Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510318/113546
\newcommand{\Xwdth}[1]{\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep+#1\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcommand{\multiX}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\hsize=\Xwdth{#1}}#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Example Table}
    \label{example-table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
          \hline
          \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Example Table} \\
          \hline
          Very very long text &  \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Very very long text} & \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Very very long text} & \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Very very very long text} & \multiX{2}{X|}{Very very long text} \\
          \cline{1-1}\cline{5-6}
          \multirow[t]{5}{=}{Very very long text} & & & & Very very long text & Very very long text \\
          \cline{2-6}
          & Very very long text & Very very long text & Very very long text & Very very long text & Very very long text \\
          \cline{2-6} 
             & {Very very Very very Very very long text
          \itemlist{%
          \item Item number one
          \item Item number two
          }} & & & & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]